# get an ambiguous use of subscript error while using Alamofire and AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, alamofire, subscript

I use Alamofire framework to call a web service and get a song. After that I want to play the song with AVAudioPlayer from AVFoundation library. However when I import AVFoundation library part of the Alamofire code shows the 'ambiguous use of subscript' error. Here is where the error appears.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myurl).responseJSON
    {
            response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value
            {
                let tt=JSON[CategoryRow.sharedindex.item] as? NSDictionary...}}
```

the error appears in the last line.

Comment: Also use optional downcasting to tell the compiler the type of `response.result.value`

Comment: Many thanks, my friend :) @EricD.